# 'Scaffold.geometryOf() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold' using Hero Animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm currently having some problems using a Hero Animation on a custom BottomAppBar i created following this tutorial (https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-bottomappbar-navigation-with-fab-8b962bb55013)

During the transition between one page and another, the widget turns red with a "Scaffold.geometryOf() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold" exception.

Like this:

https://gfycat.com/SingleSociableHornbill

The bottomappbar is rendered correctly in any other case and if i remove the hero animation there is no exception.

The Hero widget that wraps the FAB works just fine.

Here's the code (in both of the pages):

```dart
Scaffold(
          appBar: ...
          body: ...
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Hero(tag:"PROVA", child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
          label: Text("Aggiungi", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: addNewItem),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Hero(
        tag: HERO_TAG_BOTTOMAPPBAR,
      child: CustomBottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.grey[800],
        selectedColor: Colors.orange,
)
```

`CustomBottomAppBar` is a class that extends a StatefulWidget.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

Thank You!

Alessandro

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but to anyone else that stumbled upon this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30647 . As of today, the workaround is to wrap the Hero's child inside Material.